# Chromatic Number of graph of a set of squares

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, discrete-geometry

We are given a set of squares in the plane with sides parallel to the x-y axes. 
We know that intersection of every three of them is empty.

Show that we can color these squares with red, blue and green such that each two squares with a intersection receive different colors.

Comment: I'm not sure but it seems like any such graph would be planar. The result then follows from Grotzsch's theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S$ be the set of squares and $E = \{\{s_1, s_2\}: s_1,s_2 \in S \text{ and } s_1  \text{ intersect } s_2\}$.

The graph $(S, E)$ has a planar embedding in the plane where each vertex, $s \in S$, is placed in the center of the square $s$ and each edge, $(s_1, s_2) \in E$ is embedded as a straight line from the vertices $s_1$ to $s_2$. I leave it to the OP to show it is a planar embedding. Hint: show that if an edge in this embedding crosses another edge there is a mutual intersection of at least three squares.

Then as @David E. Roberson stated this follows from [Grotzch's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6tzsch%27s_theorem).